# Reading data from an URL with URLSession

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm using URLSession to retrieve data from an url

```
func scheduleURLSession() {
    let backgroundConfigObject = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "myIdentifier...")
    let backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: backgroundConfigObject, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    let retrieveTask = backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: URL(string: "https://api.wedsblog.net/v2/index.php?bitcoin&simple")!)
    retrieveTask.resume()
}
```

When download finished

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) { }
```

Will be called. How can I read the content of downloaded file? Is ".downloadTask" the right function or shall I use another one?

Comment: You should use `dataTask`.

Comment: Thank you. With your hint I was able to figure out a solution

Answer (score 1):

Found following solution:

Implemented `URLSessionDataDelegate`

```
func scheduleURLSession() {
        let backgroundConfigObject = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "myIdentifier")
        let backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: backgroundConfigObject, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        let retrieveTask = backgroundSession.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://api.wedsblog.net/v2/index.php?bitcoin&simple")!)
        retrieveTask.resume()
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    print(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the rest of your solution?  I'm struggling with getting a complete background URLSession to run reliably.  The documentation is confusing and I haven't been able to find a complete example anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) -> Void in { // First check if error is not nil
  // Second check what is status code of your http response
  // Third do with data what you want(parse to objects)
}
```

I think it helpful.

Comment: @Wed - not a helpful response :-(  All you have actually said here is - "That's not the best way to do it, but I'm not going to tell you how to improve it"